# Reading a CSV file and converting data into python lists. ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file containing adjacency matrix of a network. When I tried to convert this data into python list of lists using the following code:

```
def main(): 
    csvfile= open('airport_CnToCn_ajc.csv','rU')
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=" ")
    alldata = list(reader)
    print alldata
    numData=[[float(i) for i in row] for row in alldata]
    print numData
```

I got an error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float ,"Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","American
```

because first row and first column of my csv file denotes source and destination of the network edges.

Is there an alternate to overcome this error other than modifying the CSV file by deleting first row and first column. If I follow the later approach, I would lose track of the nodes.

Comment: Why did you set the delimiter to a space when you appear to have comma-separated values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. You can skip the first row and the first column:

   ```
   def main():
      with open('airport_CnToCn_ajs.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
          reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
          next(reader) # Skip first row
          rows = list(reader)
          data = [float(i) for i in row[1:] for row in rows] # skip first column
   ```
2. You can use a `DictReader`:

   ```
   def main():
      with open('airport_CnToCn_ajs.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
          reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
          rows = list(reader)
          data = []
          for row in rows:
             i = []
             i.append(row['columna']) # Your data columns
             i.append(row['columnb'])
             data.append(map(float, i)) # convert to float
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the first row and column are not needed, you could skip them in iteration.

```
def main(): 
    with open('airport_CnToCn_ajc.csv','rU') as csvfile:
      reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
      alldata = list(reader)[1:]
    print alldata
    numData=[[float(i) for i in row[1:]] for row in alldata]
    print numData
```

Or, to reduce some copies (likely unneeded):

```
reader_iter = csv.reader(csvfile)
next(reader_iter)
alldata = list(reader_iter)
```